# Application LoadBalancer in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, http-headers, google-cloud-load-balancer, gcp-load-balancer

In GCP, I am running three NodeJS APIs in a single instance with three different port numbers (3000, 3001, and 3002), and I created an external application load balancer using the HTTPS front end. I also created a backend service for the three port numbers. The load balancer is attached to the instance group.

If I am requesting the URL "https://example.com/" reaching port 3000 This is working well for me for the single-backend service. but I need to pass this same URL, "https://example.com/" with different HTTP headers and values. For example, if I request the URL "https://example.com/" port 3000 needs to be reached, but if I request the same URL "https://example.com/" with the "mydealsapi" HTTP headers, port 3001 needs to be reached, and again, if I request the same URL "https://example.com/" with the "appapi" HTTP headers, port 3002 needs to be reached.

Comment: Link to a header based routing example: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-query-and-header-routing#http-header-based-routing

Answer (score 1):

Posting Mr. @JohnHanley comment as answer. I agree with the link provided. Just to elaborate on this concern the [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-query-and-header-routing#http-header-based-routing) is composed on how you can add custom HTTP headers, validating the URL and updating URL map.

Since backend service is not indicated from the post, let me also share this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/features#backends) wherein various backend types are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use forwarding rules in Google Cloud. It depends on if you have a global or regional load balancer what you have available. But you can create forwarding rules that route traffic to a specific port.

Here are the docs for more info: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts#external_fr

You can create forwarding rules through the GC console or you can create them using the gcloud cli using the

`gcloud compute forwarding-rules create`

Depending on the load blancer type, you can use ths "--ports==" flag.

Here is a doc for that: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/forwarding-rules/create

**Note:  Port specification requirements vary depending on the load-balancing scheme and target. For more information, refer to https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts#port_specifications.**

Comment: I already provided a link with examples to show how to use HTTP header-based routing in my comment. None of your links are related to HTTP header-based routing. Your answer does not explain any details on parsing HTTP headers or applying routing rules based on header values.